# How to see and use the Chef resource collection

Tags: resources, chef-infra

I am using Jenkins Chef Cookbook from Chef Supermarket.

It provides a `jenkins_command` resource/provider. This allows me for example to reload Jenkins configuration

```
jenkins_command 'reload-configuration'
```

This useful but I do not want to reload configuration for each Chef client run.

The problem now is that it does not seem to be possible to notify this resource to execute.

First I defined the resource with action `:nothing`

```
jenkins_command 'reload-configuration' do
  action :nothing
end
```

On resources that should trigger reload of configuration I added

```
notifies :execute, 'jenkins_command[reload_configuration]', :delayed
```

This results in the message similar to

> jenkins_command[reload_configuration] cannot be found in the resource
>   collection

It is unclear to me why this doesn't work. Does this mean that the resource is a resource but not added to the resource collection?

Or could it be that I should notify the resource using a different name?

How can I see what the resource collection looks like? Is there a way to see what is part of it?

There is `resources` object but that object is alway empty `[]`. I can inspect that using `Chef::Log` or using `log` resource, it is always empty.

What is the correct way to inspect the resource collection? The Chef documentation does not provide any information https://docs.chef.io/resource.html. It only states that we should be able to use any resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I believe your problem is due to the `-` vs `_`.  you name the resource `reload-configuration` but you notify `reload_configuration`.

Second, anytime you try to touch the resource collection you are getting into rocky territory.  You can find it in `run_context.resource_collection`  Use at your own risk.

Answer (score 1):

`resources` isn't an object per se, it is a method call defined in `Chef::Recipe`: https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/f4a47f9e248d99fe6c284bcbff7c2b05d6dd0484/lib/chef/recipe.rb#L82

You can either use that helper or call other methods on the collection directly but this way lies madness.